# Android sending data to server (very little base knowledge)

Tags: android

I am looking to create a hobby project to lock my brother's apartment doors from his droid phone. I want to setup a simple server app on his pc that will control this from the server side, and have android just send some data to a website on some port or other in a simple view when a button is pressed.

I've found several similar questions but all of them assume more base knowledge than what I have. Things like 'just fire up WebService' or 'use raw sockets' are above my head for now. I have no idea what JSON -is- so it doesn't help me to hear that I should use it.

What I'm asking is what ways can I do what I need to on android and which is probably the best method? I want to do this the -right- way so I can add more features later like sending data back to confirm lock and monitoring for last time his door was opened.

I'm not asking for source, I'll do my homework.

Comment: Do you have any hardware knowledge? Or is the door already electrically active?

Comment: I am an EE, and here's my plan. I'll build a small box with a stepper motor in it to lock it, then use ANT+ to wirelessly talk to the PC. That's easy and in my realm of knowhow. The server app should be easy too. It's the droid part I'm new to.

Answer (score 1):

Given you're saying you don't have much basic knowledge, I'd suggest you're starting from the wrong end -- first try to write some code that will make the door unlock, that you can run on the PC.  Then make it accessible from a website, thinking carefully about how you stop unauthorised users from accessing it.  Lastly, look into triggering that website from an Android app.  That way, you're breaking the problem down into pieces that can will give you something useful at each step.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I prefer to attack the hardest part first, though. I figure I'll do the droid app and server app first, and just make the server app flash a light or something in a c# gui to start.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best way to do this is to send an HTTP "request" to an HTTP servlet running under a server that's running on the remote workstation. HTTPS is even more secure, but may not be necessary.

You'll need an HTTP server (for example, Apache or Google Web Services), a particular servlet to receive the request. Once you have that, you can send requests from Android. You construct a URL for a GET or a header block for a POST. Don't be confused; you're not necessarily getting anything. HTTP URLs can contain information that gets passed to the servlet, this is called "encoding" information onto the URL. Look at some URLs; if you see a "?" followed by some variable names and data (for example, ?id=newbie), that's data encoded on the URL. A quick and dirty way to send data from a browser or application to a remote workstation.

You'll also need to look at the Java classes in java.net and android.net

It's impossible to do more than point you in the right directions without writing an entire book.

In summary, learn how to communicate with a web server running on a remote workstation. Based on your learning, you'll be able to construct a simple web client on Android that can send info to your brother's PC.

IMHO, raw sockets are *not* the way to go. Some people may *think* they're easier than HTTP, but I think that they're harder because documentation is so sparse. Go with whatever way is in most use; there's lots of documentation and people have already made all the mistakes.